# What is the cause of the bad performance of NGINX / PHP which host only 1 Wordpress website

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php7

I spawned a LXC container on our (Proxmox) hypervisor (we run multiple containers on it without any performance issue). I installed NGINX and PHP7.4 on it and host (currently) only 1 Wordpress website. This website is pretty simple and contains only the WooCommerce plugin, WPML plugin(s) and FooEvents plugin(s) and uses a default template (twenty twenty). Only 3 products are configured.For developing purposes i currently visit the website only via the internal network via an host file entry.

Before i continue, the "hardware" setup:

**Hypervisor**

- HP DL360G9
- 2TB of raid 1 Enterprise HP SSD's for VM's and LXC only
- 128GB of raid1 Enterprise HP SSD for Proxmox OS
- 2x Xeon E5-2680v3
- Running ca. 10 containers with same specs (1 of them is the webserver)
- average CPU load 2%
- average RAM usage 10%
- average IO delay 0%
- average SWAP usage 0%
- Average network traffic <50kbps

**LXC container specs**

- 4096 MB RAM
- 2 v-cores
- 50GB storage
- average CPU load 0.2%
- average RAM usage 3%
- average SWAP usage 0%
- Average network traffic <10kbps

When i visit website pages, the performance is acceptable to good (ca. 300ms - 750ms) even when i think it could be faster as the hypervisor and LXC container is almost idling..

Though when i'm working in the admin pannel (/wp-admin) the performance is very poor. E.g. when i'm logged in an navigate from the dashboard to the plugins page, i need to wait around 31! seconds every time
[image]

It needs around 16 seconds to visit the theme page
[image]
During the page loads, the LXC container do not have any big CPU, RAM or disk IO peaks or something which lets me think that NGINX or PHP is responsible for this..

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # *** is just for obfuscastion
        root /var/www/webshop.internal.***.de;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name webshop.internal.axxteq.de;

        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

There are no entries in the `/var/logs/nginx/error.log` or `/var/log/php7.4-fpm.log` error logs.
I have no idea how i can debug this or how i can find out where the issue is. Are there extra configurations required except for the NGINX configuration i added to this question?

Answer (score 0):

From the way it sounds, it looks like a common issue of some code trying to knock to a remote server that isn't accessible.

For example, a plugin that talks to its vendor's website to notify you of updates (most common)

If that is the case, then the delay you experience is the timeout to curl requests. [Enable PHP-FPM log](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-log-and-fix-slow-php-requests) and then you can see which code is causing the wait.